# how to add number to the title of sections and subsection using the titlesec package

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I am using the `titlesec` package but the numbering of section and subsections disappeared. I need to retrieve it. my code is

```
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\color{blue}\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\bfseries}{}{1em}{}
```

I need to achive the following specs:
  Main headings: Arial, Size 12, Bold, Uppercase, Center Justified.

Sub-headings: Arial, Size 12, Bold, Title case, Left Justified.

Comment: Add `\thesection` in the second mandatory argument. Similarly, add `\thesubsection` in the the corresponding command. Your specifications don't say anything about changing colors,  and yet you have a change to blue?

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Thank you very much for this help, Really I do not need the blue line but it was just for test. If I want to achieve the given specs what should I do?

Answer (score 16):

You should use `\thesection` and `\thesubsection` in the appropriate places; also `\MakeUppercase` should go in the last argument for `\section`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tgtermes,tgheros} % use your preferred ones for the fonts
\usepackage{lipsum} % this is just to produce some text

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries\sffamily\filcenter}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]
  {\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries\sffamily}
  {\thesubsection}
  {1em}
  {}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\section{A section title}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{A subsection title}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]