# No numbers with titlesec and [hang]

Tags: sectioning, numbering, titlesec

If I use the `[hang]` format of the `titlesec` package (using a quite recent version of `titlesec`, namely `2016/03/15 v2.10.1`, and TeX Live 2015), the section is not numbered. It seems that the `[hang]` option disables the numbering.

MWE (taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109866/24664, the image there shows my expected outcome):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tgtermes,tgheros} % use your preferred ones for the fonts
\usepackage{lipsum} % this is just to produce some text

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries\sffamily\filcenter}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]
  {\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries\sffamily}
  {\thesubsection}
  {1em}
  {}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\section{A section title}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{A subsection title}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Is this a bug in the `titlesec` package?

Comment: I get them numbered as expected.

Comment: My .log files says `titlesec 2016/03/21 v2.10.2`.

Comment: @Alenanno: I tried version `2.10.2` from CTAN and got the expected output. Thank you!

Comment: Mmh possible duplicate? [titlesec: loss of section numbering with the new update (2016/03/15)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299969/4778)

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate. I searched, but I did not found it before I asked my question. Sorry.

Comment: No problem! :D It can happen. I'll vote to close so people are redirected to that question.