# Package titlesec Error: Unknown shape

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I am trying to modify the basic `article` class section headers so that the main section level is centered and has the format "1. XXXXX ".  To accomplish this I am trying to use the `titlesec` package.  However when I specify the `titelformat` I get the following error:

> Package titlesec Error: Unknown shape.

Even a minimum working example that I found and tweaked from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109838/how-to-add-number-to-the-title-of-sections-and-subsection-using-the-titlesec-pac) won't work.  What I specifically tried compiling using `pdflatex` was

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries\sffamily\filecenter}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}

\thesection{Behold}
Blah blah blah.  Something about something important, maybe.

\end{document}
```

Is there an issue with my LaTeX distribution or has something changed since this example was made and now?  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! There are two errors in your code: the centring directive is `\filcenter`, not \filecenter. And the section call is `\section{Behold}`, not  `\thesection` (which is the command  to print the current section number). With these corrections, it compiles normally for me.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome!  I made the corrections that you pointed out in your comment, but it still didn't compile for me.  As I was typing a reply to your comment I realized that I grabbed the .sty files from CTAN.  Previously in my haste though I only grabbed the .sty files and not the ancillary files.  Once I downloaded those every thing started working.  Thank you for your help with my errors!

Comment: But why didn't you install titlesec with the package manager of your distribution?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not entirely sure.  I'm using Ubuntu for the first time after switch from Mac and did a get-apt to get Latex.  Most likely I did not get a complete package.  There have been several packages that I've found missing that I've had to go find and add myself.

Comment: But you have `tlmgr`?

Comment: Yes, I do have it.  I'll have to look into how to use it to make sure my distribution is complete.